# Find the required Revenue to reach a certain ROI, given the Overhead and Margin

Tags: fractions, economics, percentages

Let's say there is a retail shop. I want to know the required revenue to reach an ROI of 10%.

$$\begin{align} ROI = \frac{Revenue}{Overhead + COGS} - 1 \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} \frac{100,000}{30,000 + 30,000} - 1 = 0.66 \end{align}$$

A shop making 100,000 with an overhead of 30,000 and cost of goods sold of another 30,000... Would generate 40,000 in profits i.e. ROI of 66%.

$$\begin{align} COGS = \frac{Revenue}{1 + Margin} \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} \frac{100,000}{1 + 1} = 50,000 \end{align}$$

If we sell a product with a margin of 100% i.e. double the COGS of 50,000, we'd have a revenue of 100,000.

So, how can I combine these two equations, and simplify the expression...

$$\begin{align} \frac{Revenue}{Overhead + \frac{Revenue}{1 + Margin}} - 1 \end{align}$$

In order to get...

$$\begin{align} Revenue = {} ... \end{align}$$

**I want to plug in the Overhead, Margin and ROI, in order to get the required Revenue.**

Comment: So basically you have the equation
$$
ROI = \frac{Revenue}{Overhead + \frac{Revenue}{1 + Margin}} - 1 
$$
I would start by multiplying both sides by the denominator: 
$$
ROI \cdot \left( Overhead + \frac{Revenue}{1 + Margin} \right) = Revenue - Overhead - \frac{Revenue}{1 + Margin}
$$
Then open the parentheses, group terms with a factor of $Revenue$ together ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm going to give everything shorter names: we'll call revenue $R$, overhead $O$, margin $M$, and ROI $I$, just because I'm lazy and it's less typing.

Then adding $1$ to your last line, we have $$\dfrac{R}{O+\frac{R}{1+M}}= 1+I.$$
Multiplying that by $O + \frac{R}{1+M}$ we obtain $$R = (1+I)O + \frac{(1+I)R}{1+M}.$$
Multiplying that by $1 + M$, we have $$R(1+M) = (1+I)O(1+M) + (1+I)R.$$
Subtracting $(1+I)R$ from both sides and simplifying, we have 
$$R(M - I) = (1+I)(1+M)O.$$
Finally, divide by $M - I$ to obtain $$R = \dfrac{(1+I)(1+M)O}{M-I}$$ as required.

Comment: and overhead and margin are not zero plus that margin is different from ROI.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. Awesome!